# How to define transforms on a resource in a REST way?

Tags: rest, hateoas, json-api

I'm designing a REST api, following best practices, including a form of hypermedia/hateoas. I'm using [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/) for the design guidelines, which seems to be pretty complete.

Currently, I have a need for:

1. combining 2 resources in a response (a Resource A and a related Resource B). I do this using the [Compound Documents - structure](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure-compound-documents)  as specified in [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/). Or also commonly known as *resource expansion*
2. formatting the result of 1. in a specialized way so it can be readily consumed by a specialized client that expects said formatting.

My problem is with *2*. How do I correctly represent this in a REST-way? It seems I may need a separate endpoint, but that wouldn't be 'RESTy', since that implies a separate resource, while it's just a transformation of the output of the same resource.

Any references on how to do this?

Comment: It is allowed to use multiple URLs to identify the same resource.

Comment: You can add a new MIME type, MIME type parameters, for example profile, etc... but I think the new URL is the best solution.

Comment: Btw. this so called json api is far from a perfect REST solution. You might be interested in this (if you have time to read): http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/third-generation-web-apis-bridging-the-gap-between-rest-and-linked-data.pdf

Comment: @inf3rno: great link. Though on quickly skimming I can't find any mention of jsonapi. Any references on why it might not be a good place to start?

Comment: It is not about jsonapi, it is about REST and semantic web. First 50 pages answer that part. :D But to be short: I did not say jsonapi and other plain JSON solutions are not good to start with, they are just not perfect. With them you won't be able to reuse the client or write general clients for APIs having similar services. In order to do that you need a common contract between the APIs and the clients written in RDF.

Comment: Ahh yes gotcha. Thanks for summarizing! :)

Comment: I checked this jsonapi, it actually violates other aspects of the uniform interface constraints, for example by sending `"op": "replace"` (RPC style) in the request body instead of sending resource representations only. Other problem that I cannot see form descriptions. It seems like they confuse URLs with hyperlinks... I would rather use [HAL+JSON](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) with a form extension like [this](https://github.com/weluse/dougrain-forms) if I were you. It is still not perfect, but at least does not violate REST constraints.

Comment: You can solve your 1. problem by defining a new resource (lets call at AB) which contains both A and B as sub-resources. You can solve your 2. problem by defining a new URL for the AB resource, for example `/resources/AB?special=true`. Other possible solution to use [prefer header](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7240) with the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a header or a query param to handle this.

When the client needs specific formatting, they could add an additional header to the request something like `Format:Indented` or something like `http:\\myapp.com\resouces\myresource?format=indented`

Or if the server is formatting and wants the client to know that the response is pre-formatted, the server could add a `Format` response header to notify the client that response is formatted.